# How to import dataset of images from two directories and adding labels for training and testing?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to use CNN for images classification in Python. Now I have a question about how to load the dataset.

I have a dataset with two directories: one directory contains 50,000 jpg files for training images (with ID between 0-49,999) and another directory contains 10,000 jpg files for testing (ID between 0-9,999). There is also a training label CSV file. This is a CSV file with two columns. The first column indicates the samples id and the second column indicates the label of the samples. The labels are between 0 and 9. I know the mapping between the pictures and labels.

How to import the dataset in Python ?

I try to used the code for CIFAR-10 dataset to load my dataset, I have code as follows:

```
# example of loading the cifar10 dataset
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras.datasets import cifar10
# load dataset
(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = cifar10.load_data()
# summarize loaded dataset
print('Train: X=%s, y=%s' % (trainX.shape, trainy.shape))
print('Test: X=%s, y=%s' % (testX.shape, testy.shape))
# plot first few images
for i in range(9):
    # define subplot
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    # plot raw pixel data
    pyplot.imshow(trainX[i])
# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

For CIFAR-10 dataset, the shape of training dataset and test dataset are
`Train: X=(50000, 32, 32, 3), y=(50000, 1)`
`Test: X=(10000, 32, 32, 3), y=(10000, 1)`

Can I get the similar train dataset and test dataset for my directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to load images from directory.

Sample code below

```
  data_dir ='directory/path'     
  train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask how to label them as in `(trainX, trainy), (testX, testy) = cifar10.load_data()`?